# Is it possible to apply for a short-stay visa while I'm in Schengen area with a tourist visa?

Tags: schengen, france, tourist-visas, study, visa-renewals

I'm going to visit my friends in France as a tourist. Can apply for a language school while I'm there? Is it possible to change my 30-day Schengen visa to a 90- day short-stay Schengen visa?

I got my tourist visa from Poland's Embassy in Tehran, and I'll leave Poland for France at the end of my journey. If there is a chance to apply for a short-stay visa in this situation, how long would it take?

Answer (score 3):

What you have is already a short-stay Schengen visa so you are in effect asking whether you can extend an existing Schengen visa or apply for another one while you are in the area and the answer is generally no.

The rules for national visas are different and there are situation in which it could in theory be possible to apply for a long-stay study visa. While it's difficult to know exactly without much more details, that is probably impossible in your situation.